# Find a value in a column in function of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Assuming that the value exists, how can I for example, create another column "testFinal" in the dataframe where I will have the absolute value of df["test"]- " df["test"] which is 0.2 seconds after "
for example, the first value for testFinal is the absolute value of the difference between 2 and the value 0.2 seconds after -> so 8, the result is abs(2-8) = 6

My goal is to calculate "testFinal"

I don't know if its clear so here is the example

[image]

NB : the Timestamp is not homogeneous, so the interval between two values can be different over time

Thanks a lot

Here is the code for the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.10],
                   'test':[2,22,8,4,5,4,5,3,54,23,89],
                   'testFinal':[6,18,3,0,0,1,49,20,35,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
```

Comment: I think you should explain better what exactly you want to have in testFinal. I'm pretty lost. For example, how to calculate for the first row.

Comment: sure, I made some edits

Comment: What should be in testFinal if the value 0.2s later does not exist?

Comment: I assume that this value exists (in fact the thing I asked I did some calculations to make sure that there will be a value)

Comment: The only thing to be conscious of is that the Timestamp is not homogeneous, so it could be 0.1 0.2 0.3   0. 31 0.32 0.33 0.4 0.5 ...

Comment: You understand the basic issues with floating-point arithmetic, yes? You won't necessarily have `0.3 - 0.1` comparing equal to `0.2`.

Comment: I think so,I don't know if it's a good idea but I usually use round() to bypass this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a new temporary column `temp` obtained from converting the `Timestamp` column to `timedelta` using [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then set this `temp` column as dataframe `index`, then create a new column `testFinal` having the values as this new index + `0.2 seconds`, then using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), map the `testFinal` column to the values from `df['test']` column, thus now the `testFinal` column should have values corresponding to the values in `test` column `0.2s` later, thereafter you can subtract the values in the `testFinal` and `test` column to get the desired result:

```
df['temp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('temp')

df['testFinal'] = df.index + pd.Timedelta(seconds=0.2)
df['testFinal'] = df['testFinal'].map(df['test']).sub(df['test']).abs()

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
# print(df)
    Timestamp  test  testFinal
0        11.1     2        6.0
1        11.2    22       18.0
2        11.3     8        3.0
3        11.4     4        0.0
4        11.5     5        0.0
5        11.6     4        1.0
6        11.7     5       49.0
7        11.8     3       20.0
8        11.9    54       35.0
9        12.0    23        NaN
10       12.1    89        NaN
```

Comment: thanks a lot, could you explain a little bit what you did please ?

Comment: I searched in some other topics but I did not found this application for the map() method, could you explain it a little bit please?

Comment: @Lukx Refer to this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/understand-map-function-to-manipulate-pandas-series-8ac340d514f7) it explains `map` in details.

Comment: @Lukx `map` as the name suggests maps the values in one series to values from the another series i.e, `one to one correspondence`

Comment: okay thank you, so if I understand well you replace the values of "testFinal" with the values in test according to the index (if you don't map using a dictionnary it would map using the index am I right ?)

Comment: @Lukx Yeah, absolutely correct, that's why we set up the index in first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy` as follows. I created a new column `test_final` to compare with the expected `testFinal` column.

```py
import numpy as np

test = df.test.values
df['test_final'] = np.abs(test - np.concatenate((test[2:], np.array([np.nan]*2)), axis=0))
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```sh
    Timestamp  test  testFinal  test_final
0        11.1     2        6.0         6.0
1        11.2    22       18.0        18.0
2        11.3     8        3.0         3.0
3        11.4     4        0.0         0.0
4        11.5     5        0.0         0.0
5        11.6     4        1.0         1.0
6        11.7     5       49.0        49.0
7        11.8     3       20.0        20.0
8        11.9    54       35.0        35.0
9        12.0    23        NaN         NaN
10       12.1    89        NaN         NaN
```